# npm install creates strange differences in package-lock.json between different machines

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I've tried googling this but couldn't find anything so trying here - we've recently upgraded to `node 16.13.0` and `npm 8.1.0`, and after doing `npm install` we get the following diffs in `package-lock.json`:

```
-      "devOptional": true
+      "dev": true
```

and

```
-      "integrity": "sha512-15Ft8p1vVEvBQDjZV6XSQULHIbRTetygyGyaF953pq/ukW0AnnHD3Kra7NasJxryWfbBrD18i11uors0CvnOwg==",
-      "requires": {}
+      "integrity": "sha512-15Ft8p1vVEvBQDjZV6XSQULHIbRTetygyGyaF953pq/ukW0AnnHD3Kra7NasJxryWfbBrD18i11uors0CvnOwg=="
```

This happens for a small percentage of packages, but that small percentage is 60ish packages and I don't understand why these differences happen (especially since we're using the same `node`/`npm`)

Comment: The specification for dev/devOptional says `dev, optional, devOptional: If the package is strictly part of the devDependencies tree, then dev will be true.  If it is strictly part of the  optionalDependencies  tree,  then optional  will  be  set.  If it is both a dev dependency and an optional dependency of a non-dev dependency, then devOptional will be set.  (An  optional  dependency  of  a  dev dependency will have both dev and optional set.)`
However that still does not explain, why it changes between installations ...

Comment: I've seen the same thing for some time now. Definitely appears to vary from machine to machine, and even day to day.

Comment: That's awful. The same happens here

Comment: Happens here as well, unsure why..

Answer (score 9):

For those who are having the same issue, check that npm config `legacy-peer-deps` is set to false

`npm config ls -l | grep legacy-peer-deps` to check its value

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps false` to set it to false

Comment: Unfortunately, it is set to false :(

Comment: just check if there you have any other npm config? Or do a comparison between the config before and after upgrade

Comment: I have no idea where the other config would be, as far as I know, there is no other config

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: That's a good question - we haven't been working on the project that much lately, so I can't tell you for certain

Comment: Fair enough. If it's public, share a link with me and I can take a look. Cheers

Comment: It's not :( but thank you for offering

Comment: This helped me, but also I had to delete my `node_modules` and run npm install again after settings update.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm quite late to the party, but I'm posting this as it might help somebody...

There are many valid reasons to use the flag "--legacy-peer-deps" when updating node-packages. This is how I ran into the problem described above.

Here's how I solved it:

- Commit and push the changes (including all the unwanted ones described above) to
  the branch of the feature I was working on.
- Delete my local folder `node_modules`.
- Checkout the main branch.
- `npm i`
- Checkout the feature's branch again.
- `npm i`

By now, all unwanted changes made/ lines added will have been removed automatically.

- Commit and push these changes.

At this point, `package-lock.json` showed that only lines that were **directly** associated with the updated package had been changed on the feature's branch.